# FOSUserBundle registration form overridden - validation problems

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've modified my registration form and added a few fields (such as First name, Last name, and Organisation name).

My application will have 2 types of users - "regular" users, that will have to provide their First name and Last name, and also "organisations", that will have to provide their organisation name.

When the form is rendered, the system detects the user's "type" and only shows the form fields relevant to that user (for example: "organisations" don't get the First name and Last name fields).

The registration works fine, but there are no validation messages shown... Even if there is an error, it is not displayed.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
```

where you extend your form.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a better idea for you to instanciate a different form for different user level, instead of doing that in templating.